# Errors on MikroC

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-errors, pic, mikroc

I am programming the pic16f1823 using mikroC and I am getting some very strange errors.

When I declare an integer an error appears and when I try to declare a char* array I get an error which says `Too many chars`. And one of the weirdest errors are '}' expected '}'.

My code is below if you spot any mistakes that would make such an error please inform me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *filter;
char *filters[25] = {'1','6','11','2','7','12','3','8','13','4','9','14','5','10','15'};//error: TOO many chars
int PositionOfFilters[] = {1,6,11,2,7,12,3,8,13,4,9,14,5,10,15};
int EEPROM_READ(void);
void main() {
     TRISA = 0;//all port A are set as outputs
     TRISC = 0;//all port C are set as outputs
     while(1){
              int prevState = RA2;//store the previous state of RA2 to see if the button was every pressed or not
              int i;
              unsigned int *address[15];
              i2c_Start();
              for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){
                    address[i] = i2c_read(0);//should return what pin is set high;
              }
              i2c_Stop();
           if(RA2 != prevState){ //if the state of RA2 is different than the previous state that means the button was pressed
                  LCD_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
                  int position;//error invalid experison
                  int on;
                  Lcd_Out(2,14,'LOC'); //prints out the we are on local mode
                  for(i = 0; i<16;i++){
                        if(address[i]!=0x00){ //checking to see which pin is high as well as where it's corresponding position is
                            on = address[i]; //should work because only one number shouldn't be 0x00
                            position = i; //gets the corresponding position
                            break;
                        }
                  }
                  if(on == 0x06){
                        Lcd_Out(1,3,'filter 15');//must be filter 15 because there is no other filter that has 0x06;
                  }
                  else{
                       int j;
                       for(j = 0; j < 15; j++){
                             if(PositionOfFilters[j] == position){
                                   //we know what filter we are at
                                   filter = filters[j];
                                   break;
                             }
                     } '}' expected '}' found MyProject.c
                       char *finalFilter = 'filter ' + filter;
                       Lcd_Out(1,3,finalFilter);//Prints out which filter is on
                  }
                  //for the eeprom
                  EEPROM_READ();

           }
           else{
                Lcd_Out(2,14,'REM'); //will print out REM for remote mode
           }
     }
}

int EEPROM_READ(void){
      //figure out how long the eeprom data is
      //start storing the data in a array and then return that array
      //do this by using i2c_start() then eeprom_read(address) then i2c_restart
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that total number of `{` and `}` are equal? I prefer to format with `{` on new line below `for` and `if` - at the same column position like `}`. It improves the readability for such cases.

Comment: Just checked that and all the { and } are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filters declaration is wrong. You declared a char pointer array and init it with char literals.

You need pointer to string of one char

```
char *filters[25] = { "1", "6", "11", "2", "7", "12", "3", "8", "13", "4", "9", "14", "5", "10", "15" };
```

It depends on what `filters` is used for.

---

Second problem is

```
Lcd_Out(1, 3, 'filter 15');
```

surely this code must eb

```
Lcd_Out(1, 3, "filter 15");
```

C-strings literals must be sorrounded by `"` not `'`

---

Third problem

```
char *finalFilter = 'filter ' + filter;
```

it is wrong. As explained before, string must be `"filter"` and using [c](/questions/tagged/c) you cannot concatenate strings in that way.
You can do, for example

```
char finalFilter[32];
sprintf(finalFilter, "%s%s", "filter", filter);
```

Comment: for the first edit that you did you send to change char *  to just char that still gives me the error

Comment: @MOHAMMEDSALEH No. First version of answer I gave you 2 choice. Looking better to your code you need the option I left in my answer now: char * with strings as initizalizer...

Comment: thank you I figured it out and thanks for the other mistakes that you pointed out

Comment: @MOHAMMEDSALEH You're welcome. If enough, close the question as answered flagging the correct answer.